# Style Issue in SFSE profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Have anyone experienced some styling issues in profile page of SFSE? I tried a hard refresh for my chrome browser but still it's there. Collapsing sections. Not much clear the info.
[image: style_issue]

Comment: Confirmed, experiencing same issue (Chrome on Win7)

Comment: wonder why no one responding what's going on. btw, atm whole bar chart is disappeared for me

Comment: Same for me. Who is responsible / capable of fixing this? Who did or will contact them?

Comment: Also experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I have noticed this as well.  The About you section also seems to have moved its way down the page as well.  I saw this in Chrome originally, but have tested and see it in Mozilla as well.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For me, it is totally broken:

> [image]

Comment: Yah, time to time the issue comes in different manner. May be they are working on this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been fixed, anyone still encountering this problem?

Comment: Yes, looks like it has been fixed.